# How to prove ¬ 2 < 1 in agda?

Tags: agda, plfa

I think I must missing something to prove `¬ 2 < 1`.

I have

```
¬1<0 : ¬ (1 < 0)
¬1<0 = λ()

¬0<0 : ¬ (0 < 0)
¬0<0 = λ()

¬2<0 : ¬ (2 < 0)
¬2<0 = λ()


contraposition : ∀ {A B : Set}
→ (A → B)
    -----------
→ (¬ B → ¬ A)
contraposition f ¬y x = ¬y (f x)
```

If I want to prove `¬ 2 < 1` I can use  `contraposition` like this:

```
¬2<1 : ¬ (2 < 1)
¬2<1 =  contraposition 2<1->1<0 ¬1<0
```

But `2<1->1<0 : 2 < 1 → 1 < 0` seem not simple to prove

We can simple `s<s` on `1 < 0`.

```
1<0->2<1 : 1 < 0 → 2 < 1
1<0->2<1  x =  s<s x
```

But we can't easy do same thing on `2 < 1` Because we have `<`

```
data _<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set where

    z<s : ∀ {n : ℕ}
        ------------
        → zero < suc n

    s<s : ∀ {m n : ℕ}
        → m < n
        -------------
        → suc m < suc n
```

I know the

```
_∸_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ  -
m     ∸ zero   =  m
zero  ∸ suc n  =  zero
suc m ∸ suc n  =  m ∸ n
```

may have help to prove `2<1->1<0`.  My intuition tell me, introduce `_∸_` to prove this problem will be more complicate. There must something I don't know in Agda and it is obvious.

PS:

I must say "The solutions" will don't effect the people who take responsibility for themself. One student is good because he is good. 
I ask help here not because I want to get some answer to do exam. I am not a student anymore. I just got difficult and need some tips to go on. 
It need `1500` reputation to create tag likse `plfa`. Can anyone help it?

Comment: I think it should be trivial to show that `suc m < suc n -> m < n`.

Comment: `p<p : ∀ (m n : ℕ) → suc m < suc n → m < n` is not so trivial. I try it before.  András Kovács 's method is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many alternative approaches can be contrived. For your approach to work, you can prove `2<1->1<0`, which is simple enough.

```
sm<sn->m<n : {m n : ℕ} -> suc m < suc n -> m < n
sm<sn->m<n (s<s m<n) = m<n

¬2<1 : ¬ (2 < 1)
¬2<1 = contraposition sm<sn->m<n ¬1<0
```

Comment: Thanks. I see ` (s<s m<n)` on left side in `<-trans`.  `sm<sn->m<n` and `contraposition` and combine as `cong` to do `¬n<n` . such like `¬n<n (suc n) =  contraposition sn<sn->n<n ( ¬n<n n)` But I can not do same thing use András Kovács answer like `¬n<n (suc n) =  (s<s ( ¬n<n n))`. Both you give a good answer. In my case accept any one is ok. As I mention here. The accept answer is for you.

Answer (score 3):

To prove this particular lemma, you only need to pattern match on the argument:

```
¬2<1 : ¬ 2 < 1
¬2<1 (s≤s ())
```

All `¬n<m` propositions for `n`, `m` literals are provable by matching on `m` number of `s≤s`-s, if `n` is actually greater. For example:

```
¬5<3 : ¬ 5 < 3
¬5<3 (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s ())))
```

The point is to dig down into the case where the right side is `zero` and the left is `suc`, because there is trivially no `_<_` constructor with that shape.

Comment: Hi. In my agda env:  ¬2<1 : ¬2<1 (s<s ()) works.  Thanks.

Comment: I must say on the syntax why `¬0<0 : ¬ 0 < 0  ¬0<0 =  λ()` can work . But after introduce `s<s` (Seem have no expr can work such like `¬1<1' =  (s<s (λ ()))` or `λ(s<s ())`  Because I will use `s<s` on some lemma (such like cong for the induction)

Answer (score 1):

Chapter Decidable of PLFA shows you how Agda can compute either m < n or ¬ (m < n) for any given m and n. In particular, it defines a function ¬s≤s : ∀ {m n : ℕ} → ¬ (m ≤ n) → ¬ (suc m ≤ suc n) that does exactly what you want.